# Usb charger not charging only with vcc and gnd

Tags: usb, charger, 5v

I want to charge my tablet on the wall. And I have a charger behind the tablet and connected 2 wires to vcc and gnd, the same pins as usb female, it turns out that I can't have more than 10 mA. If I connect with usb cable I get values like 2000mA.
Shouldnt it be the same? Is it because of the shield? Should I short the shield to GND?

Comment: We don't know what type of power supply you have, what type of tablet, where you found Vcc and GND to connect to, what "USB female" is and how and where you measured the 10 mA limit. I think you need to edit your question to improve it and add a diagram. Otherwise it is likely to be closed as "Unclear what you are asking."

Comment: Consider the gauge and quality of connections, you could have a high resistance point.

Comment: there are more than power leads and shield in a USB cable